# How to make child elements arranged horizontally in BFC?

Tags: html, css, sass, less

This is my html code:

```html
    <div className={styles['box']}>
      <div className={styles['left']}></div>
      <div className={styles['right']}>
        <div className={styles['item']}></div>
        <div className={styles['item']}></div>
        <div className={styles['item']}></div>
        <div className={styles['item']}></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is my css code:

```css
.box {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.right {
  background: lightcoral;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border: 3px solid saddlebrown;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
.left {
  background: lightseagreen;
  border: 3px solid saddlebrown;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
.item{
  background: lightslategrey;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

This is what they look like.
[image]

I want items to be arranged horizontally, and items still under left, What should I do? Generally speaking, left and right overlap, and then the elements in right can be arranged from left to right, which is not affected by left. The elements in left can be arranged from top to bottom and will not be affected by right.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the .items straight horizontal, you can try this:

```
.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: lightcoral;
  opacity: 0.5;
  border: 3px solid saddlebrown;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```